# How do I add a line break between each Text Node of an UL in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

The application receives a user input and then dynamically creates a new node when a button is clicked.. However, I am unable to add a line break between each appended node in my appended li.

Following is the code:

```js
  btn.onclick = function () {
    text = optionField.value;

    Li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));

    Li.setAttribute("style", "display: block;");

    ul.appendChild(Li);
  };
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: could you describe your question more precisely, or show what is your current result?because in this codepen it works perfectly - https://codepen.io/withnowaifu/pen/XWMVvPp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a break, you could add a  `<BR>` tag to the `LI` element ***BEFORE*** you add the ***textnode***

```js
btn.onclick = function () {

  text = optionField.value;

  //add a break tag here, before the appended textNode not after it
  Li.appendChild(document.createElement('br'))

  Li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));

  Li.setAttribute("style", "display: block;");

  ul.appendChild(Li);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add a `<br>` tag between nodes, it probably should help

```
text = optionField.value;
btn.onclick = function () {
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));

  li.setAttribute("style", "display: block;");

  ul.appendChild(Li);
  ul.appendChild(document.createElement('br'))
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work. I don't understand why, as this seems like the most suitable solution.

Comment: can you provide a working example of what you have?